# Variant Date Field Format

Tags: sxa

I am using variant Date field to display format as "25 September 2017", when language changed to Arabic it displays Hijri Date, is there a way to control the format to show gregorian calendar with the month names translated to arabic?

Answer (score 5):

Dates are rendered as culture-specific unless specified explicitly.

SXA provide date format from variant item to field renderer and later Sitecore handle everything.
[image]

The only thing you can change is format:
[image]

If you cannot fix it with different variant of language, then you will have to provide your `culture` manually.

There is a class in Sitecore called `DataRendered` used by FieldRendered to render a date. Notice that there is a way of providing `culture`

[image]

What does it mean? That you can provide an additional parameter `culture` to a field rendered and explicitly say what your culture should be.

Unfortunately, SXA does not provide you an ability to inject custom parameters to field renderer (good idea to add this in the future).

Here is a processor to override:
`Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.Pipelines.RenderVariantField.RenderVariantField`

Find following method
`protected virtual Control CreateFieldRenderer(Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.Fields.VariantField variantField, Item item, bool isControlEditable, bool isFromComposite)`

and extend `control.Parameters` string with your additional parameter. It depends on you where you get it (item, configuration).

Good luck.